# What to do about a manager that assigns me heavy workload, is verbally abusive and doesn't appreciate my work?

Tags: manager

My boss is insufferable, doesn't care about his employees, only cares about the goals the upper management assigns to him and that's why he's only concerned with results, such as reaching the required goal of online visitors each day/week/month (It's a website).

Another reason why it's bad is because my manager's knowledge on the technical side is very low, which means that any effort to explain why this article/social media post didn't attract enough visitors is dubbed as a "lame excuse". He's always tense and tries to micromanage us on every possible level. He comes pretty early, stressed out, forgets what I told him yesterday about work so he asks again about it and every time I get out a different response from him.
He also assigns extra work for me, like writing reports to the upper management that he should be doing. Reports such as "weekly traffic report" or a summary of the stories we covered because, of course, the upper management doesn't have time to read what we do.

He also makes fun of team several times, but not in front of them. He talks to one of my colleagues about this person "who writes worse than vegetables, if vegetables can write" and things like that, which obviously affects our team negatively when words fly around. Even his attitude clearly shows his opinion of the team.

Two weeks ago, he called me to his office and told me that the report I wrote the day before "sucked" and the reason? I was supposed to write the report in the past tense and I wrote in the future tense instead. I was very tired and stressed out because I had to finish the report on time and in addition to my normal job requirements, which are writing, editing, proof reading, and translating pieces from one language to another.

He daily/weekly sends me to management meetings not because he wants me to get promoted, only because he wants his boss to see that he brings his employees to these meetings to have a good impression that he "cares". One time, he commented on my hair and told me to cut it and said "you know some people here get a warning because of their public appearance in the workplace". He said that in front of others. I liked my hair like that and was forced to cut it.

My question is: Do I have enough reasons to file complaint at the human resources department? How to make him stop without jeopardizing my role at the company?

Comment: "only cares about the goals the upper management assigns to him and that's why he's only concerned with results, such as reaching the required goal" -- in other words, he's a manager and is doing his job? If you want something different, convince him that the company benefits from that change.

Comment: I would focus on the second question and probably just delete your first question because as Joe Strazzere points out, this depends on your HR department. This being said, I don't see how he's jeopardizing your role. If anything, I see it as you jeopardizing his role since you want to go through official channels to complain about him. Now, if you're worried about putting yourself in the line of fire for a complaint that won't go through, honestly, that's a judgment call you have to make yourself.

Comment: Also, while you have very detailed examples, some may consider this to be a rant, so I would consider brainstorming some of my own suggestions.

Comment: While it is true the top 10% of managers would not behave this way, 90% of managers are not in the top 10%. It is counterproductive to get upset at thisbehavior.  Just realize he is a jerk and move on with your life. BTW, the extra work is part of your normal work. It is certainly what I would expect any manager to assign. Currently about 33% of my job consists of tasks outside my  job description. Through my career that has ranged from 15% to 100%. It has never approached 0%. So stop resenting doing what you are assigned. Your boss could be more diplomatic, but many are not.

Answer (score 6):

> How to make him stop without jeopardizing my role at the company?

You can't, this isn't a realistic expectation, anything you do, particularly complaining about your superiors can get political very quickly and be a cause for all sorts of issues including termination (although that might not be the reason given). It might not backfire on you, but there is no way of telling that until it's been tried.

If you are that unhappy my advice would be to job search and soldier on until you find a new job. Because quite frankly many managers are like this and many employees just plod through their day and let it wash over them. Your description of your manager wouldn't have worried me at all back in my working days, you can only get upset if you allow yourself to be.

In saying that, I do believe you have more than enough to talk to HR about if you want to go down that track, and you may well benefit yourself or others by doing so, but it's not a given, it's a risk, weigh it up carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You can always file a complaint with HR, and it sounds like you should.  Especially if he's been verbally abusive to you in front of others, they can corroborate your story and add weight.  I would say get your resume ready and start looking outside your company as well, because while most companies have (and enforce) non-reprisal policies for situations like this, there's always the chance that you'll be better off in another place.